# Contact Form 7 - Submit Form not working After Ajax Request

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, plugin-contact-form-7

I am using `Contact Form 7 with ajax jquery`. The first part is for user to insert `vehicle number` and `email`.

If success, it will load contact form 7 via ajax. When I click on submit, it will redirect to a new page and will output 0. I had made a research on google and found out the `wpcf7-submit` function.

I tried to make an alert function and it response as expected. How do I want to use it with contact form 7 and email the form details if no error on the form?

> **Coding**

*form.php*

```
<?php
get_header(); 
// Include all the theme functions    
?>

<form name="season-form" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="">
  <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
    <label for="carNo" id="label-cust"> Vehicle Registration No</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="vehicle_no" id="vehicle_no" placeholder="BHK1991">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group form-group-lg">
    <label for="email" id="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="myMail@example.com">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_payment">Make Payment</button>
</form>
<div id="result"></div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

*function.php*

```
function _myConfirmHandler()
{
    if(isset($_POST['vehicle_no']))
    {
        $vehicle_no = $_POST['vehicle_no'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        echo do_shortcode('[cfdb-table form="season parking form_copy" show="your-name,mail,your-platno,your-location" filter="your-platno=' . $vehicle_no . '" headers="your-name=Name,mail=Email,your-platno=Registration No.,your-location=Parking Location"]');

        // Display the Form 
        echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="6959" title="Payment season Form_Post"]');
    }

    wp_die();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_confirmRequest', '_myConfirmHandler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_confirmRequest', '_myConfirmHandler');
```

*jquery.js*

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#submit_payment').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var str = $("form[name=season-form]").serialize();
        //alert(str);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '//www.ktmparking.com.my/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            data: str + '&action=confirmRequest' 
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);

            $(".cal").datepicker({
            showOn: "button",
            dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
                buttonImage: "http://theonlytutorials.com/demo/x_office_calendar.png",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                showAnim: 'slideDown',
                duration: 'fast',
                showButtonPanel: true
            });

            $('.wpcf7-submit').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                alert('Submit button press!');
            }); 

        });
    });    
});
```

Do I have to rewrite the post method on the form and email the details if success?

Comment: I think you have added your own `jQuery` code for **CF7**.  Am, I right?

Comment: do you mean the jQuery library? I did not add the jquery

Comment: No not library, are you using your own code for mail submission..

Comment: Nope. For jQuery, I just use the code above. For the mail submission, I want to use the function provided by Contact Form 7. From the previous code that you made, are you able to submit the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have been loading **CF-7** form using `ajax` by that means required scripts for that form never executed for that. And, because of that thing your form not working as it was expected to be.

You have to `re-initiate` the scripts of **CF-7** for the particular form. Here, is the updated PHP code.

Now, your ajax will be:

```
<?php

function _myConfirmHandler()
{
    if(isset($_POST['vehicle_no']))
    {
        $vehicle_no = $_POST['vehicle_no'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];

        echo do_shortcode('[cfdb-table form="season parking form_copy" show="your-name,mail,your-platno,your-location" filter="your-platno=' . $vehicle_no . '" headers="your-name=Name,mail=Email,your-platno=Registration No.,your-location=Parking Location"]');

        // Display the Form 
        echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="6959" title="Payment season Form_Post"]');
    ?>
     <script>
        jQuery('.wpcf7 > form').initForm();
        var urL = jQuery('.wpcf7 > form').attr('action').split('#');
        jQuery('.wpcf7 > form').attr('action', "#" + urL[1]);
    </script>
    <?php
    }

    wp_die();
}

?>
```

**Update:**
initForm is no longer present since CF7 5.4

Thank You [@Chris Pink](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/57686/chris-pink)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm not in front of my desk now. Will give the update later. May I know what does the script do?

Comment: It will initiate the `CF7` script on your form. You were loading form using ajax because of which it was not initiated on particular form. I will wait for your reply. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Will do. Where can I get the details or documentation on that?

Comment: You want documentation of what?

Comment: Regarding the script. Eg, the detail function on 'wpc7InitForm()'

Comment: I hope on website of `Contact Form 7`.

Comment: I update the code with the script. It give a response but it just show the loading spinner without any mail send or data validation.

Comment: are you using it on localserver or live server?

Comment: It's a live server

Comment: I has made some updates in code, please check those.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58171/discussion-between-amran-and-amit-chauhan).

Comment: Im thankful for this answer because it led me in the right direction, but i must point out that it didnt work for me as-is. I was getting an error saying that $form.wpc7InitForm() was not a function, which led me to a fix found on the Wordpress forums. It turned out that the function is not `$form.wpc7InitForm()`, but rather `wpc7.initForm($form)` ... see the answer by @tapitoconnectey near the bottom -  https://wordpress.org/support/topic/wpcf7initform-is-not-a-function/

Comment: @mroncetwice answer has been updated as per your comment, I hope it will work now without any error. Thanks for the update. :)

Comment: Note initForm is no longer present since CF7 5.4